# .NET app upload directly to S3

Tags: .net, amazon-s3

I need to modify an existing .NET application to upload large files directly to our S3 file store. (It currently uses FTP.)

What's the best way of doing this without compromising our security? It would be easy to compile our access keys into the app, but this would compromise every user's files. There's got to be another way, but I'm just not seeing it! Any thoughts out there?

Answer (score 0):

Properly obfuscated assemblies should ease any fears you might have of distributing the app with the keys embedded.  We use a product called Demeanor.  Works well enough for us.  Some others linked below.

[Demeanor](http://www.wiseowl.com/products/products.aspx)
[Dotfuscator](http://preemptive.com/products/dotfuscator/overview)
[Codeveil](http://xheo.com/products/code-protection)